# Update previous record to inactive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am reading data into SQL on a daily basis. When I read the data into SQL, I need to keep track of when the record changed. This is done through the columns 'Record Version', 'Effective Date, and 'IsActive' - as seen below.

| ID | Name | Record Version | Effective Date | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EU | 1 | 2020/01/01 | 1 |

When a new record version is added, the previous record needs to change to 'IsActive' = 0, and the new record added needs to have a record version that increments by 1, and the field 'IsActive' needs to be updated to 1 - as seen in the table below.

| ID | Name | Record Version | Effective Date | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EU | 1 | 2020/01/01 | 0 |
| 1 | Europe | 2 | 2021/01/01 | 1 |

I am currently able to add the records in a table through a Stored Procedure with the INSERT INTO statement. However, I am unable to update the fields for the previous and new records.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is called an "UPSERT". Have a search of the portmanteau and you'll find a wealth of examples of how to do this. Alternatively, for a completely different solution, you could look into temporal tables.

Comment: Looking at your example, there is no way to connect these two records as being different versions of the same record. They do not have something like an ID that enables you to determine this. Unless this is for instance a table with only one (active) record. Please provide us with enough information to enable us to help you.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, I have updated the question with the ID. Sorry still finding my feet with SQL.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for the comment. I am investigating 'UPSERT'.

Comment: @Larnu I disagree that this is a "pure" `UPSERT` - as that operation refers to situations where you are either updating an existing record or inserting it. OP's scenario is to `INSERT` the new record and update the obsolete one. You're bang on with this being a case for temporal tables, though

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be accomplished in two statements: one to `UPDATE` the obsolete record(s) and a second one to `INSERT` the new record.

Assuming that the process "reading the data into the table" has the ID of the new record, that would look something like this:

```
UPDATE <table>
   SET IsActive = 0
 WHERE ID = @recordID
       AND IsActive = 1;
```

Followed by a single writing statement:

```
INSERT INTO <table> 
       (ID, Name, RecordVersion, EffectiveDate, IsActive)
VALUES (@ID, @Name, @RecordVersion, @EffectiveDate, 1);
```

This is a generic approach, and there are other ways to construct the `INSERT` depending on what's appropriate for your use.

You should also consider whether it's appropriate to enclose this operation in an explicit `TRANSACTION` and the applicability of handling exceptions through a `TRY-CATCH`

A more advanced topic on the same subject is "Temporal Tables" mentioned in comments by @Larnu